# using ajax to get more form fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a page that has a form on it:

index.php

```
 <script>
var userId = $('#userId').val();
 $('#moreFields').click (function()
 {
                    $.ajax(
                    {  
                            type: "POST",  
                            url: "addToForm.php",
                            data: "userId="+userId,
                            success: function(result)
                            { 
                              $('#dialog').html(result);
                            }
                    });
  });
  </script>


  <form id='userInfo' name='userInfo' method='POST' action='#'>
   <input type='text' name='userName' id='userName'>
   <select name='optionChoice' id='optionChoice'>
       <option value='1'>1</option>
       <option value='2'>2</option>
       <option value='3'>3</option>
       <option value='4'>4</option>
   </select>
 <input type='button' id='moreFields' name='moreFields' value='Add Fields'>

  <div id='dialog'></div>
```

addtoForm.php

```
 <input type='text' name='job' id='job'>
 <input type='text' name='salary' id='salary'>
```

based on the option the user selects. I want to add additional fields.  I do this by sending an ajax call to addtoForm.php that has the form fields in it. These form fields show up in a dialog.  My question is, will these form fields be attributed to the same form id as the form on index.php page? Will the form with id userInfo have userName,optionChoice,job, and salary as elements in the form?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  You can add more data items to the POST by simply adding more items to the `data` parameter in the AJAX call.  It's not clear what any of that has to do with `addtoForm.php` though, since you're not showing any server-side code for that resource.

Comment: Im trying to build the form using ajax.  this is all way before "submit" of any kind of the actual form data.  I want to be able to add form elements to the original form.  addtoForm.php contains the additonal form elements I want to add for the user to fill out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code wont add the additional fields to the form, it just adds them to the div#dialog which is outside the form.

To add the fields to the form you could use jquery's berfore() method:

```
$('#moreFields').before(result);
```

However, as your addtoform.php doe not do any calculation at all, and simple returns html, the whole ajax request is pointless. You may as well just add the fields with js:

```
$('#moreFields').click (function(){
        $(this).before('<input type=\'text\' name=\'job\' id=\'job\'> <input type=\'text\' name=\'salary\' id=\'salary\'>');
});
```

Comment: the addtoform.php is doing some calculations, i have omitted them because its code that gets in the way of my question.  so i see what .before does and it looks like it will work however, how can i get the result to show in the #dialog div, and not on index.php?

Comment: @bart2puck Oh i see. Is div#dialog within the form tags? If so, you original code should work just fine. What errors caused you to ask this question?

Comment: when i post the form,  the $_POST array only has #userInfo and #optionChoice in it.